Build Dynamic ElasticSearch query using OR clause in C#
The following is a query written in C#. It leverages Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch version 8.13.7. This is NOT the NEST client. This is the ASP.NET client. It doesn't have a lot of documentation.
submissions = await localClient.SearchAsync<SubmissionDto>(SUBMISSION_INDEX, s => s
   .Query(q => q
      .Bool(b => b
         .Must(
            m => m.Term(tt => tt.Field(f => f.Ori).Value(myTenants.ElementAt(0).Item1.ToLower())),
            m => m.Term(tt => tt.Field(f => f.Cri).Value(myTenants.ElementAt(0).Item2.ToLower())))
         .Filter(f => f
            .Range(rr => rr
               .DateRange(dr => dr
                 .Field(f => f.SubmissionCreation)
                   .Gte(startDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"))
                   .Lte(endDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"))
                    .TimeZone("America/New_York"))))))
    .Size(MAX_DOCUMENTS)
    .Sort(sort => sort
        .Field(f => f.SubmissionCreation, d => d
        .Order(SortOrder.Desc))));

The query uses myTenants which is passed in as a parameter to the method. The type of myTenants is IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>>. Each item in the list represents and ORI/CRI pair. I need to update the query to traverse the entire myTenants list. The query should return all SubmissionDto where the ORI/CRI combination is equal to those in myTenants
I've tried a bunch of different queries

My understanding of your question is you would like to retrieve all documents that have the same key value pairs. So a query something like this?
(Ori = A && Cri = B) || (Ori = C && Cri = D) || ...

This can be written like so:
await client.SearchAsync<SubmissionDto>("indexname", s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Should(
                tenants.Select<Tenant, Action<QueryDescriptor<SubmissionDto>>>(tenant => d => d.
                    Bool(b => b
                        .Must(
                            m => m.Term(t => t.Field(dto => dto.Ori).Value(tenant.Ori)),
                            m => m.Term(t => t.Field(dto => dto.Cri).Value(tenant.Cri))
                        )
                    )
                ).ToArray()
            )
        )
    )
);


Yes that is what i was trying to accomplish. I updated my code as follows per your suggestion. But now the should clause is always empty. The message returned from elastic is : "[14:18] [bool] failed to parse field [should]" CausedBy: "Type: illegal_argument_exception Reason: "query malformed, empty clause found at [14:18]"" @issung

@TiffanyLynn Very sorry about that, there was a subtle error in the setup of the lambdas, I have tested it locally this time and verified it outputs the expected DSL. Try it now.
